# Is there a simple way to do Query By Example in iBATIS?

Tags: java, ibatis, query-by-example

I had hoped this was baked into the most recent release, but if it is, I can't find the docs via a [simple Google search](http://www.google.com/search?q=iBATIS+%22query+by+example%22). Failing that, I'd prefer a simple library, but I'll settle for a tutorial.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ibator can help you with this. Let it autogenerate everything, and you'll find  by-Example Queries in the SQL Maps, as well as corresponding Java bindings in the DAOs.

Check "Example Class Usage Notes" on http://ibatis.apache.org/docs/tools/ibator/ for more information.

Comment: I wouldn't call it simple, but this is better than anything else I've found.